# when i using kendo ui template it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

when using kendo ui template like this :

```
var token = kendo.template("<tr><td>#=fname#</td><td>#=DOB#</td>
              <td>#=gender#</td><td>#=active#</td><td></td><td></td><td>
               <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-sl' 
                   id='removeIcon' data-index='#=index#'
                      data-id='#=id#'  onclick='removeUser(this)'>
               </span></td></tr>");
```

it's give me :

```
token = (function(data/**/) {var $kendoOutput, $kendoHtmlEncode = 
 kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){$kendoOutput='<tr><td>'+(fname)+'</td><td>'+
 (DOB)+'</td><td>'+(gender)+'</td><td>'+(active)+'</td><td></td><td></td>
 <td><span class=\'glyphicon glyphicon-remove icon-sl\' id=\'removeIcon\' 
  data-index=\''+(index)+'\'  data-id=\''+(id)+'\'  
  onclick=\'removeUser(this)\'></span></td></tr>';}return $kendoOutput;
 })
```

and i want it return the html with only the between hash is correct

Answer (score 0):

its not clear from your question what are you asking for ?

A template is like a blueprint. you create the template and at runtime provide data to the template and ask it to render the markup. Template will replace the placeholder you have place like #= # with acutal value and give you the markup.

Basic usage of kendo ui template is shown here as a demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/templates/index

Do take a look at the demo. Do explain clearly what is your issue and what is the output you are looking for.